# Looped animation stops

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a twinkling star background effect in all my app screens. I put this code in the initial view controller file:

```
 for index in 1...50 {

    var x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(400))
    var y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(700))

    // Set the Center of the Circle
    // 1
    var circleCenter = CGPointMake(x,y)

    // Set a random Circle Radius
    // 2
    var circleWidth = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(7) + 2)
    var circleHeight = circleWidth

    // Create a new CircleView
    // 3
    var circleView = circleview(frame: CGRectMake(circleCenter.x, circleCenter.y, circleWidth, circleHeight))
    view.addSubview(circleView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(1000 + arc4random_uniform(100)) / 1000, delay: NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 1000, options: .CurveEaseIn | .Repeat | .Autoreverse, animations: {circleView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { finished in
            println("thing!") })


}
```

And I put the same code in each additional view controller file but the circles don't appear. If I click to go back to the initial screen, the circles again don't appear (even though they do the first time the app is loaded).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In which method is the code above running in?

Comment: many things could go wrong. Are all view controller files tied to their counterpart in the interface builder. If you start with a single view app, the first one is created for you. The rest needs some extra set up. 
If they run the first time, but don't when you come back, you probably set it up in viewdidload. Try viewwillappear. This gets fired each time the view is shown. Not only when the view is first loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something runs the first time a view appears, but doesn't when you navigate back, you probably set it up in viewdidload. Try viewwillappear. This gets fired each time the view is shown. Not only when the view is first loaded.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // your code that needs to run each time a view appears
}
```